# Ipad Application without nib starts and then immediately closes

Tags: iphone, ipad, nib

Im writing an ipad application.
So far what I have is a Delegate and Root view controller which initializes the menu screen that starts the game.

I am not using a nib, so in my main class, i start the application with

`UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"PictionaryAppDelegate");`

In my delegate, I have a applicationDidFinishLaunching method which creates an instance of the viewcontroller. In the viewcontroller, I have a load views method which sets up the menu view with all the buttons etc.

When I run it, it starts, and then automatically goes to the dealloc method of the delegate and ends. can someone please tell me why my menu isnt being loaded.

The entire project is attached
[here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/6d9szl0ep34v0bc/Pictionary.zip) on media fire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing:

```
- (void)loadView {

 CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
 UIView *menuScreen = [self view];
```

This is a big **no no**.

`loadView` is there to generate the `view` if it is `nil`. So what you are doing here is you try to access `view` (which isn't in place yet as we are in `loadView`), and this calls `loadView`, and you get that endless recursion with an exploding stack.